# How does ANTLR4 handle optional rules?

Tags: context-free, formal-grammars, compilers

Are the following two `stat` rules equivalant?

```
stat : 'if' expr 'then' stat ('else' stat)? ;
```

```
stat : 'if' expr 'then' stat    // with higher priority
     | 'if' expr 'then' stat 'else' stat
     ;
```

That is, does ANTLR 4 always put the alternative without the optional part before the one with the optional part, or vice versa? Any official documents/source code for this?